# How to place a div below another div?

Tags: html, css

I have a `#slider` div with an image. After that, I have a `#content` div which has text. I have tried `position:relative` so I think it should come after the previous div, I mean `#slider` but here it is not coming that way.

What is the problem here? How to overcome it?

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="http://oi43.tinypic.com/25k319l.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="text">
        sample text
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slider {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    height:400px;
}
#slider img {
    width:100%;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
}

#content #text {
    position:relative;
    width:950px;
    height:215px;
    color:red;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CaZY7/)

Comment: Why do you have the `position:absolute` on the #slider? That is what is causing your issue.

Comment: oh are you saying #content will keep only position relative and static in account? Am i correct?

Comment: if your #slider is set to position:absolute it makes it out of the document flow.. so anything below that tag will be pushed up.. so you need to either remove position:absolute.. or you need to add a top margin to the #content to the same height as the #slider with some extra pixels for space between the #slider

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have set `#slider` as `absolute`, which means that it "is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor" (confusing, right?). Meanwhile, `#content` div is placed relative, which means "relative to its normal position". So the position of the 2 divs is not related.

You can read about CSS positioning [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

If you set both to `relative`, the divs will be one after the other, as shown here:

```css
#slider {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    height:400px;
   
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
}
#slider img {
    width:100%;
}

#content {
    position:relative;
}

#content #text {
    position:relative;
    width:950px;
    height:215px;
    color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uorgj4e1/

Comment: Thanks change your fiddle

Comment: jsfiddle updated and improved! I didn't know I had to click update.

Answer (score 0):

what about changing the **position: relative** on your **#content #text** div to **position: absolute**

```
#content #text {
   position:absolute;
   width:950px;
   height:215px;
   color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CaZY7/12/

then you can use the css properties **left** and **top** to position within the #content div

Comment: No the red text should come after the image

Comment: do you mean on top of stacked.. or after the image making it below ?