# place one div below another div

Tags: html, css

if I have :

```
<div>content1</div>
<div>content2</div>
```

how can I use css to display them as:

```
content2
content1
```

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to place a div below another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338323/how-to-place-a-div-below-another-div)

Comment: You can use the order property on 1st child with value 2, and it well help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order` property to re-order the elements visually

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper div:first-child {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>content1</div>
  <div>content2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.c1 {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="c1">content1</div>
  <div class="c2">content2</div>
</div>
```

Using `order:number` property on children, u can change their order.

More on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)